# Why does x={1:4} return a 1x1 cell and x={1 2 3 4} return a 1x4 cell? [MATLAB]

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

Why does `x={1:4}` return a **1x1 cell** and `x={1 2 3 4}` return a **1x4 cell**?

I would like to obtain a **1xn cell** using `x={1:n}` statement. The reason is that I need to construct a struct

```
 struct('field1', [], 'field2', x, 'field3', ' message')
```

such that the struct is

[image]

The problem is if I use `x={1:4}`, the struct becomes

[image]

But I want the struct to look like the first picture. I need to use the `x={1:n}` statement as **`n`** can be very large.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `1:4` gives the numeric vector `[1 2 3 4]`, the assignment `x = {1:4}` is the same as `x = {[1 2 3 4]}`. So `x` is a 1×1 cell array containing a 1×4 vector.

On the other hand, `x = {1 2 3 4}` creates a 1×4 cell array of numbers.

To create something like `x = {1 2 3 4}` with varying size `n`, you can first create the numeric vector `1:n` and then apply [`num2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), which puts each number in a separate cell:

```
x = num2cell(1:n);
```

Comment: `{[1 2 3 4}` should be `{[1 2 3 4]}`. Too minor to be an edit with at least 6 characters though. ;)

Comment: @MatthiasW Thanks! Corrected